# Set In Property File - Bcrypt datasource password over Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Using  Spring boot 2+
I have an application.properties file with the followings:

This is a part of my `application.properties`:

`spring.datasource.password={bcrypt}xxxxxxx`

Without bcrypt the application works perfectly but using this, my code return error in DB JPA login.

I have added this to my security class:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

But it doesn’t solve my issue.
still login failure to DB.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Remove the `{bcrypt}`, it is only used if you are using `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`.  See this answer to understand it bit more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701158/spring-boot-jdbc-authentication-failing/62704290#62704290

Comment: If it still fails, put a breakpoint in `BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches` method, it will compare the password you sent and the password you setup in `application.properties`

Comment: Hi, @KavithakaranKanapathippillai thanks for your answer . im lost as your answer is related to Bcrypt password from DB.
My Whole point is to hash my DB Password Connection..
Why is it so hard?

Comment: your password is from db too. See `jdbcAuthentication()` in your config

Comment: Do you have a github repo?

Comment: Hi @KavithakaranKanapathippillai , unfortunately no :(

Comment: Did you try removing the `{bcrypt}` part?

Comment: It is not difficult, just put a breakpoint in `BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches` method, copy the value of `encodedPassword` and put it in `application.properties`. (because you might have copied the bcrypt password incorrectly`

Comment: I have removed the `{bcrypt}`
I have set a new Hashed key in case something wrong with the current key.
Both didnt succeed

Comment: What is it? i dont have it in the code: `BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches`
Where does it need to be? do you have example?

Comment: It is the spring library classes and it will be available in your IDE

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai - yes

Comment: _"My Whole point is to hash my DB Password Connection.. Why is it so hard?"_ - because it's not possible to do. Hashing is an irreversible process, but you need the actual password to authenticate with the database.

Comment: Ok! @1615903 - Now im Progressing! 
So this cannot be done?? So How i can protect my DB Password to be not seen over the application.properties file ?

Comment: You could use environment variables, or something like [jasypt](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this quest by using "spring boot jasypt" api.
Thank you very much for your assistant.
Yaniv

Here is a tutorial that can assist you in case you need.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt

Answer (score 0):

In somewhere in your code must have some kind of password comparing, so if your password is saved and encrypted by bcrypt, you must check it with bycrypt aswell
with

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encryptedPassword);
```

for example, in my code:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Autowired
  private final UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired
  private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    User user = userRepository.find.findByUsername(username);
    //You have to check if user exist or not before compares the password
    if (passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
        //Password matches then login
    } else {
        //Password did not match, bad credentials.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @kyito , This is a DATASOURCE JDBC Login For SQL Server. 
the Datasource is a default datasource withouth a class in the Spring boot pacakge.
How can i Setup the Password of the datasource (JDBC) to be Hashed?

Comment: Can you provide your code how did you do the login? Somewhere in you code has to check if user and password matches.